# Can open host by \\hostname but cannot ping by hostname

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, ping, hostname

I have two laptops connected by NetGear JNR3210 router: one (running Windows 2000) is directly attached by a cable and one (running Windows 7 x64) is attached via WiFi.

On both laptops when I open `Network Neighborhood` **I see names of both computers and can open shared folders on them**. I can also `ping` them by IP, but when I try to `ping` remote computer by the hostname, it returns "Unknown host".

On both machines the `Computer Browser` Service is running.

What should I do for enabling `ping` by hostname in my home network?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both machines have DNS entries, typically your router's address. Also make sure to disable or allow echo requests (ping) through the windows firewall.

Comment: As I understand, my router plays the role of DNS server. In the router interface I see both the IPs and the names of both machines. Probably this means that they have DNS entries. On both machines `ping` works for IPs but not for hostnames. Probably this means that antiviruses do not block `ping`.

Comment: If you do an ipconfig /all on the command line do you see an IP address under the DNS entry. Anti virus does not block pings but the windows firewall does.

Comment: `ipconfig /all` returns the Windows IP configuration (which contains the hostname) followed by list of adapters and associated properties (which contains the IP). So I surely see the IP in the output.