# SSH is unable to connect by hostname

Tags: networking, router, ssh, openssh, hostname

I had a curious issue recently after I changed addresses, ISP, and router.  I have a linux box running openssh which I was using as a NAS.  I was able to log into the device using a command similar to the one below:

`ssh username@NAS`

Where NAS was the hostname of the NAS device.
This used to work on my LAN and over direct ethernet connection and allowed me to connect the devices.

After moving to a new address, and using Xfinity and its associated router, I suddenly find myself unable to connect to my NAS via its hostname, both over the router and over even stranger, over direct ethernet connection.  However, I can connect to the device by its IP from other computers, and can connect it to itself from a terminal on the same device with the hostname instead of IP.

Here are some of the things observed:

- ssh from another connected (LAN (ethernet and wifi) through router or direct ethernet connection) device returns "Name or service not known".
- `hostname -I`  and `ip addr` both return the IP associated with this NAS that I can use to ssh into the device via `ssh username@IPaddress`
- `nmap -sP` is able to find the NAS IP over the LAN network when used from one of the devices I am trying to use to connect.
- `hostname` and the contents of `/etc/hosts` both indicate the hostname of the computer is `NAS`, and when I ssh into the device using its IP, the terminal prompt tells me `username@NAS~$`

I would much rather connect to the device by name rather than have to connect by an IP address, and although I can add the ip address to `/etc/hosts` on all my devices, I don't want to have to do that and want to simply be able to connect to the device by its name over LAN.  More than anything, I'm a bit baffled as to why what was working with one router and location seems to not be working anymore, even over a direct connection.  Does anyone know why this could have occurred?  I'm seeing some similar problems that others have posted suggesting the problem might have something to do with DNS and the router: [Can open host by \\hostname but cannot ping by hostname](https://superuser.com/questions/837819/can-open-host-by-hostname-but-cannot-ping-by-hostname)
but I'm not sure if this is the same type of situation.

Comment: Are tools such as `host NAS` or `nslookup NAS` able to find the name?

Comment: "host NAS" returns (SERVFAIL) and "nslookup NAS"  returns SERVFAIL as well when trying to connect externally.  On the NAS itself, it gives 127.0.1.1, which may have something to do with localhost.